# Annotations when fields/columns not match

Tags: java, json, annotations, jackson

Suppose you have a class:

```
@Entity(name = "Person")
public class Person{
    @Column(name = "iAge")
    private int _age;
}
```

What I am doing to expose access methods is:

```
@JsonProperty("age")
public int getAge() {
    return _age;
}

@JsonProperty("age")
public void setAge(int _age) {
    this._age = _age;
}
```

Is there a better way without duplicating annotations?

*Note that the field name (_age) is different from the column of the table (**i**Age).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's cannot be done because `@JsonProperty` and `@Coulmn` is a different frameworks annotations, the best way I can think you can do it in more pretty way is like that :

```
@Entity(name = "Person")
public class Person{
    @Column(name = "iAge")
    @JsonProperty("age")
    private int _age;
}
```

And make your `ObjectMapper` look at your fields

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the names as in this particular example - then you may omit @JsonProperty as the name of the property will be automatically inherited from getAge() method name.